# Common YAML Properties file for gradle and spring

Tags: java, spring, gradle, properties, flyway

I am doing project in Spring MVC 4.1 + Gradle + FlywayDB as for db migrations.

I uses flyway gradle plugin to configure any db migration before running my application. Eg: Id do following command before my deployment

```
gradle flywayMigrate
```

I am using multiple yaml files are my project properties files, for example db configurations and other project specific configurations.(Multiple files, since each environment is using its on configuration files names as application-dev.yml, application-live.yml etc)
The specific problem I am facing here, I need to configure 1 db configuration inside my build.gradle for flyway db configuration, and for application I need to do the same configuration on the application.yml file.

Is there a way with gradle that I can feed these properties from the same file rather not configuring them again in build gradle or in gradle.properties file. I can do some gradle scripting to read my configuration files and can do some hacks....But rather is there any proper gradle plugin or some other pretested tools anybody using... Please let me know....Or if any other better solution is there...Please share if you don't mind.